# gRPC for kotlin android: Import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto" does not work

Tags: android, kotlin, protocol-buffers, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I created a gRPC project very similar to the example gRPC for kotlin android project at 
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/example-kotlin/android/helloworld

The building process works if i use the example proto files.
But now, that I have replaced the protofiles with different ones, Gradle fails to build my project.

This is the failing proto file:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package tensorflow.serving;
option cc_enable_arenas = true;

import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto";

// Metadata for an inference request such as the model name and version.
message ModelSpec {
  // Required servable name.
  string name = 1;

  // Optional version.
  google.protobuf.Int64Value version = 2;

  // A named signature to evaluate. If unspecified, the default signature will
  // be used.
  string signature_name = 3;
}
```

The error message is:

```
  Cause: protoc: stdout: . stderr: app/build/extracted-include-protos/main: warning: directory does not exist.
  app/build/extracted-include-protos/main: warning: directory does not exist.
  app/src/debug/proto: warning: directory does not exist.
  app/src/debug/proto: warning: directory does not exist.
  google/protobuf/wrappers.proto: File not found.
  model.proto: Import "google/protobuf/wrappers.proto" was not found or had errors.
  model.proto:30:3: "google.protobuf.Int64Value" is not defined.
```

Comment: Hey ! Could you find a workaround? I am currently wanting to import `google/api/annotations.proto`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "well-known" protos that are shipped with the normal protobuf jar are not included in the protobuf-lite jar, which the kotlin Android example is using. The issue is tracked in https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1889

As a workaround, you can add the protos from the normal protobuf jar to your project:

```
dependencies {
  protobuf 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.5.1'
}
```